# How to check availability of Published Pipeline Artifacts in azure pipeline release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created an azure build pipe line and published the artifacts. While releasing I want to know the artifact is created or not. How to check the availability of Published Pipeline Artifacts  in azure pipeline release

Answer (score 1):

> How to check availability of Published Pipeline Artifacts in azure pipeline release

Since you have published the artifacts, you do not need to check the availability of Published Pipeline Artifacts in azure pipeline release on purpose.

That because the **built-in Download Artifacts** will check and download the Pipeline Artifacts in azure pipeline when your release source type is **Build**:

[image]

[image]

Besides, if you want to manually check the the availability of Published Pipeline Artifacts in azure pipeline release, you could use the [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to download the artifact to check it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed - this task should fail if your artifact _isn't_ available.

Comment: @ZachChilders, Yes.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT
I have different dockers to build in a single pipeline. Each time ymal artifact is created for changes occurred docker. All yaml artifacts are may or may not be changed every build.So while releasing i want to deploy created yaml artifact that's why I want to check the artifact.

Comment: @arunthomas, Thanks for you sharing the reason. How about use the Download Build Artifacts task to download the artifact? If it resolve your question?